# Elastic search having "not_analyzed" and "analyzed" together

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch. What my business needs is that I should also do a partial matching on searchable fields I ended up with wildcard queries. my query is like this :

```
{
   "query" : { 
        "wildcard" : "*search_text_here*"
    }
}
```

Suppose that I'm searching for `Red Flowers` before the above query I was using an analyzed `match` query which provided me with both results for `Red`  and  `Flowers` lonely. but now my query only works when both `Red Flowers` are present together.

Answer (score 0):

Use match phrase query as shown below for more information refer the [ES doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html):

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
         "match_phrase": {
              "title": "red floewers"
                         }
             }
}
```